# Create Checkboxes with jQuery and uncheck one when others are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to create form elements with the click of a button, which I have, but I also want to make sure if Full Registration is clicked, the others are unclicked and vise versa. If any of the others are clicked, Full Registration is unclicked. The disableFull function is an onClick on each of the checkboxes. Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#addGuest").click(function() {

        var intId = $("#guestForm div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fName = $("<label>Guest Name</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"exclusive\" id=\"guestName" + intId + "\" />&nbsp;");
        var fguestOptionFull = $("<label>Full Registration</label><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"options\" name=\"guestOptionFull\" id=\"guestOptionFull" + intId + "\" onClick=\"disableFull('guestOptionFull" + intId + "\')\" value=\"415\">");
        var fguestOptionBreakfast = $("<label>Breakfast</label><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"options\" id=\"guestOptionBreakfast" + intId + "\" onClick=\"disableFull('guestOptionFull" + intId + "\')\" value=\"100\">");
        var fguestOptionThursdayDinner = $("<label>Thursday Dinner</label><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"options\" id=\"guestOptionThursdayDinner" + intId + "\" onClick=\"disableFull('guestOptionFull" + intId + "\')\" value=\"75\">");
        var fguestOptionFridayDinner = $("<label>Friday Dinner</label><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"options\" id=\"guestOptionFridayDinner" + intId + "\" onClick=\"disableFull('guestOptionFull" + intId + "\')\" value=\"75\">");
        var fguestOptionSundayWorship = $("<label>Sunday Worship</label><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"options\" id=\"guestOptionSundayWorship" + intId + "\" value=\"0\" onClick=\"disableFull('guestOptionFull" + intId + "\')\" />");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(fguestOptionFull);
        fieldWrapper.append(fguestOptionBreakfast);
        fieldWrapper.append(fguestOptionThursdayDinner);
        fieldWrapper.append(fguestOptionFridayDinner);
        fieldWrapper.append(fguestOptionSundayWorship);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#guestForm").append(fieldWrapper);

    });

    disableFull = function(id) {
        if ($("#" + id + ":checked").length > 0) {
            this.$("input:checkbox").each(function(x) {
                if ($(x).hasclass("options")) {
                    $(x).removeAttr('checked');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            this.$("input:checkbox").each(function(x) {
                $(x).attr('checked', true);
            });

        }

    }
});​

</script>

<span id="addGuest">Add Guest</span><div id="guestForm"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear after reading it. I can not get the checkboxes to check on/off based on if the fguestOptionFull is checked or not.

Comment: Please try to be more specific. "It doesn't work" is simply not good enough. Reduce your code to the essentials and if you still don't see the problem post that code.

Comment: @champton: A Fiddle will help us to solve your question, because i think you can do this with a simple code, replacing yours.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inline onclick since you are using jquery.  You can just use the on to delegate the change event on the dynamically created elements.  Then you on click check if it's the 'guestOptionFull' option.  If it is then loop through the sibling elements and check/uncheck them.

```
$('body').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
   if ($(this).attr('name') === 'guestOptionFull' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).siblings().not('input[name=guestOptionFull]').prop('checked', false);
   }
   else if($(this).attr('name') === 'guestOptionFull' && $(this).not(':checked')) {
        $(this).siblings().not('input[name=guestOptionFull]').prop('checked', true);
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HCeBr/5/

Comment: My problem is if($('#guestOptionFull'+id).is(':checked') is true, then I need to be able to uncheck all others in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
disableFull = function(id) {
    $('#guestForm').on('click', '.fieldwrapper input:checkbox', function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'guestOptionFull1' && $(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.fieldwrapper input:checkbox').not('#guestOptionFull1').attr('checked', false);
        } else if ($(this).attr('id') != 'guestOptionFull1' && $(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#guestOptionFull1').attr('checked', false)
        }
    });
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wzUbM/)**.

Comment: So I still have the problem with trying to uncheck the a la carte options if the full registration is clicked and visa versa. Here is a jsfiddle for it: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/champton20/2VDf4/)

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want. Is your comment referring to my solution, or do you have a new issue?

Comment: I have developed some code that is almost complete. Your code did not account for multiple sets of options, which is important. In the fiddle link, I have mode solution, but just can not toggle checkboxes.